# How to resolve below error-ERROR: Child Process Error: Test runner sel (JUnitTester) has failed with retcode 1

Tags: junit, jmeter, taurus

When I ran the selenium script using Taurus and want to convert in JMX then got the error-

```java
    10:55:54 ERROR: Child Process Error: Test runner sel (JUnitTester) has failed with retcode 1
    
        10:55:54 ERROR: JUnitTester STDERR:
        May 02, 2022 10:55:50 AM com.blazemeter.taurus.junit.CustomRunner main
        INFO: Starting: [C:\Users\sss\2022-05-02_10-55-36.435651\runner.properties]
        Exception in thread "main" com.blazemeter.taurus.junit.exception.CustomRunnerException: Nothing to test
                at com.blazemeter.taurus.junit.CustomRunner.main(CustomRunner.java:54)
```

How it resolved?

Answer (score 0):

It means that [Taurus JUnit Executor](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JUnit/) failed somewhere somehow, inspect logs in the [Artifacts Directory](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ArtifactsDir/) and look for Java/JUnit-related errors there.

Most probably JUnit executor wasn't able to detect any test cases to run, it's impossible to tell for sure what is the root cause without seeing the full logs and your automation code.

Be aware that you can use another approach not involving Taurus, i.e.

1. Kick off [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000271458-Creating-the-Proxy-Recorder)
2. Configure your tests to use the above recorder as the [proxy](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/capabilities/shared/#proxy)
3. Run your tests from IDE or console
4. The BlazeMeter proxy recorder will capture the requests and convert them into .jmx file (you can also export it as "SmartJMX" with automatic detection and correlation of the dynamic parameters)